# Better Refactoring Technique in case of multiple if calls

Tags: java

I have AuditLog entity class which Im saving to DB using the method insertAuditLogs  based on LogType enum using multiple if calls

```
private void processData(LogData logObj, LogType type)
{
    if (type.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(LogType.LOG1_PROCESSING.toString()))
    {   
            AuditLog audObj = new AuditLog();
            audObj.setImportId(logObj.id);
            audObj.setLogMessage(logObj.description);
            audObj.setEntryDateTimestampJoda(null);
            audObj.setExitDateTimestampJoda(logObj.getExitDateTime());
            insertAuditLogs(audObj);
    }

    if (type.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(LogType.LOG2_PROCESSING.toString()))
    {   
            AuditLog audObj = new AuditLog();
            audObj.setImportId(logObj.id);
            audObj.setLogMessage(logObj.description);
            audObj.setEntryDateTimestampJoda(logObj.getStartDateTime());
            audObj.setExitDateTimestampJoda(logObj.getExitDateTime());
            insertAuditLogs(audObj);
    }



}
```

Question

1 How can I use Replace Method with Method Object or Extact to a Class or a Parameter Object to refactor the above calls and improve the refactoring ?

Comment: All bodies have the same code?

Comment: no description , entry date varies based on LogType

Comment: the values vary, but the logic does not. It makes no sense to have multiple `if`s but all having same logic inside

Comment: You can use a switch statement, but since all of your if statements have the same body, you should remove all of them(see Steven Baldasty's answer)

Comment: I feel above if conditions can be replaced by polymorphysms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure how the refactoring patterns you mention may apply in this case, but it looks to me (?) like the bodies of your `if` blocks are all the same. If that is the case in your real application, you should be able to simplify to:

```
private void processData(LogData logObj, LogType type) {
    AuditLog audObj = new AuditLog();
    audObj.setImportId(logObj.id);
    audObj.setLogMessage(logObj.description);
    audObj.setEntryDateTimestampJoda(logObj.getStartDateTime());
    audObj.setExitDateTimestampJoda(logObj.getExitDateTime());
    insertAuditLogs(audObj);
}
```

But if there are other `LogType` values that are not shown that you do not want logged, I suppose you would need to filter those out.

Also, here is a simpler way to compare `enum` values if you still need to do that:

```
if (type == LogType.LOG2_PROCESSING)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: logObj.description , logObj.getStartDateTime() and logObj.getExitDateTime() values vary based on LogType.

Comment: Not sure I fully understand what you mean by "vary". Are you saying that for some `LogType` values the `description`, `startDateTime`, and/or `exitDateTime` should not be included in the audit log? (That behavior would seem to differ from your code snippet...)

Comment: Please check now , I have edited my question , I removed some calls for brevity and replaced with dummy data , I have different parameters like null fo example in audObj